# How to move apps from HDD to SSD without reinstalling them?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I gave the store today, to add a new SSD to my laptop. And I assumed that when I receive the laptop, it will be as normal as before but with a good performance and an increase in speed.
But after I on the laptop, everything was new as found on a new laptop. All my apps were gone. The HDD is still there on the laptop and includes all of the files in it. Except that all the settings, browser details, apps were not there. But I have recovered the browser details. 
Now I want to know, is there a way that I can move my apps from the HDD to SSD without reinstalling, without affecting any of the files.

For example, I want to run Code Blocks. But it isn't any more there in the C drive. How can open Code Blocks without any change in it?

Hoping for a solution to this asap.

Comment: You should take this up with the store who did the drive swap. Yes it can be done, but they really should have done it for you. [They will, of course, claim that's not what you paid for, but you can stand & argue with them, for as long as it takes. They went to the trouble of installing a fresh OS on there, which you didn't ask them to do, so they *know* they're cheapskating you]

Comment: @Tetsujin It's curfew here and I won't be able to do that. Also, I will be having online lectures in a few days and I have to get everything back to normal by that time. Is there any other solutions that I can do.

Comment: It's **so** much harder to do now than it was before they took the old boot drive out. tbh, I don't know how to clone an external [or non-boot] drive to an internal [current boot] drive on Windows & have it arrive in a bootable state, sorry. The other way round would have been easy. I hope someone else picks up on this question who knows how to achieve it with only two drives & one computer.

Comment: @Tetsujin anyways thank you for the information

Comment: You can't. You must reinstall everything.

Comment: Clonezilla makes this possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple procedure for question is really not possible. Reinstalling a lot of software and manually migrating registry settings and data from the old user profile might take days even for an experienced person.

There is some [migration software](https://fossbytes.com/best-pc-migration-software-windows-macos/) available, but it should only used with very low expectations - personally i would not even recommend trying.
The easiest way to get everything back to normal until you have more time, is to remove the SSD.

If the SSD is at least as large as the HDD, then just clone - which is easy and may be finished in 1-2 hours. Most SSDs include free cloning software.
I strongly recommend to start with a full disk image (backup) of your HDD before moving around anything.

Comment: I cloned the HDD to SSD. This is a risky option, but still I did it.

Answer (score -1):

1. *Why is this difficult?* Because, Microsoft.

Windows and its commercial programs are engineered to be difficult to migrate from one drive to another as a part of copy protection for Microsoft and the [Windows ecosystem](https://www.forbes.com/sites/tonybradley/2017/10/17/the-windows-ecosystem-is-microsofts-secret-sauce) of third-part apps. Windows apps install in (at least) four different locations:

1. C:\Program Files*nameofapp* (or C:\Program Files (x86)*nameofapp* )
2. C:\Windows\System32
3. The Registry (which is built in memory, every time you boot, from five separate files)
4. Your user's Local directory (where your user profile for the app goes)

So, you have to figure out what bits of the program went where to know how to migrate it.

2. There are apps you can buy and download for migration. You can try them, but there's no guarantee they know how to migrate every app you have.  Look at [PC Trans](https://www.easeus.com/pc-transfer-software/pctrans-pro.html), [Zinstall WinWin](http://www.zinstall.com/products/zinstall-winwin), and Laplink's [PC Mover](https://ppc.laplink.com/transfer-programs-to-new-computer). I've used the latter in IT support contract assignments for HP, and it did work for the apps which HP's customer was using, but I don't know if it would work for your apps.
3. The alternative is to use an app like the open source free [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) to duplicate everything on your HDD (hard disk drive)  onto your SSD (Solid State Drive).

   This requires downloading Clonezilla's image and writing it onto a USB flash drive. After that, boot from the Clonezilla USB flash drive and choose Beginner Mode. It will walk you through the process, step by step.

You can shrink your existing Windows on the SSD before you do that, to make sure, just in case something fails, you still have your new Windows install, using a Linux LiveUSB and its gparted app; Linux and gparted are also free as in beer, just as Clonezilla for Windows is.

Comment: Anti-Microsoft blarney should be removed. One look at the installed files list for a typical Linux software package will show Windows has no corner on file "dispersion".