# How to boot from hdd?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd

HDD + SSD(boot). The laptop is booting from a new SSD with a fresh OS installed on it. Is it possible to boot from the HDD for once and then the next time to boot from the SSD again? 
How can I boot from the HDD?

Answer (score 0):

In order to change which drive you are booting from you will need to enter BIOS and change the Boot Order. On many computers you can tap the F2 or Del button repeatedly on startup. (look up for your specific machine make/model). Once you change the drive boot order, save and exit. It will boot as specified. Once finished with your changes, perform the same order of operations to revert back to the SSD. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try this and see...

Comment: Won't this involve uninstalling and reinstalling everything again?

Comment: Some machines also have an F-key to select the device for one boot, so it may not be necessary to change bios settings. @Sanu_012 the Windows installation on his HDD already exists, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1545415/how-to-move-apps-from-hdd-to-ssd-without-reinstalling-them)