# Problems because of HDD drive letter changed

Tags: ssd, environment-variables, drive-letter

The laptop is booting from the new SSD. But all my apps are on the HDD. After adding the new SSD, the drive letters of the HDD were changed. Now when I try to run an application that is on the HDD, it gives the error that it couldn't find the file. It is because the drive letters of the HDD are changed now. 
Example, "abc" application's path - E:/program files/abc/bin
After adding SSD it's new path - H:/program files/abc/bin 
but in all files, it is recorded as - E:/program files/abc/bin

Is there any possible solution for this. 
There are many applications and it is impossible to search and edit the path of every application. Is there any way to change everything with one tool. Or should I change the drive letters of the HDD to as how it was before?

Comment: why don't you boot from [the HDD again](https://superuser.com/questions/1545527/how-to-boot-from-hdd)? A number of programs need their configuration files, registry entries (and libraries) created during installation - so this could only work for **some** programs that were not installed to C:. Or why don't you follow the [cloning advice](https://superuser.com/questions/1545415/how-to-move-apps-from-hdd-to-ssd-without-reinstalling-them)?

Comment: @Furty The SSD is 120Gb. I can't clone everything

Comment: Then you should boot from the HDD again *or* buy an SSD big enough *or* go through the process installing everything again - there is no other safe way.

Comment: @Furty The HDD is partitioned into 3 drives. Is it possible to clone one of that drive to the SSD, which was before the C drive

Comment: Yes but it's not simple to clone and keep both drives, so that is something the shop should do where you bought the SSD.  (But I gues their advice also was to buy an SSD where all of the HDD contents fit.) So until you can go there again, the best you can do is to boot from the HDD again.

Comment: It is possible to clone from one partition of the HDD to the SSD if the HDD partition is smaller than the SSD when using Clonezilla http://clonezilla.org